# Write a function to find out the hire date of an employee who has joined just prior to the given date passed as input parameter in plsql

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

how to use ampersand in this program

```
create or replace function p_hire_date return date is
        &v_hire_date employees.hire_date%type;
    begin
            select hire_date into v_hire_date
            from employees
            where hire_date < v_hire_date;
              return v_hire_date;
    end;

 error PLS-00103:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a substitution variable? This is a **function**, pass parameter to it and use it in its code.

Example is based on Scott's sample schema; adjust it to your own.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_hire_date (par_date IN DATE)
  2     RETURN DATE
  3  IS
  4     retval  DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT MAX (a.hiredate)
  7       INTO retval
  8       FROM emp a
  9      WHERE a.hiredate < par_date;
 10
 11     RETURN retval;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

(You don't have to do that; it's just to know what dates represent):

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL>   SELECT ename, hiredate
  2      FROM emp
  3  ORDER BY hiredate;

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
SMITH      17.12.1980
ALLEN      20.02.1981
WARD       22.02.1981
JONES      02.04.1981
BLAKE      01.05.1981
CLARK      09.06.1981
TURNER     08.09.1981
MARTIN     28.09.1981   --> If I pass 30.09.1981, I'll get this date
KING       17.11.1981
JAMES      03.12.1981
FORD       03.12.1981
MILLER     23.01.1982
SCOTT      09.12.1982
ADAMS      12.01.1983

14 rows selected.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> SELECT f_hire_date (DATE '1981-09-30') FROM DUAL;

F_HIRE_DAT
----------
28.09.1981

SQL>
```